# Set physic body in SKTileMapNode on Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sktilemapnode

I’m using Spritekit and a SKTileMapNode.
I have some tilesand I want to add them a physic body for create a collision. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate node with a physics body the size of all of the tiles that are joined together to create 1 meta body, and have it overlay your tiles.